# Dereferencing a struct in C using only its memory address

Tags: c, struct

Suppose the memory address of a struct in C language is stored in a variable of sufficiently wide integer type, such as `uintptr_t`.
I want to read the contents of struct by casting the integer to a struct pointer and dereferencing that.

Can the original struct be reconstructed using this approach?

Comment: *Can the original struct be reconstructed using this approach?* A pointer contains no information other than the address of an object.

Comment: @WeatherVane, that's not strictly true, as a pointer also has information on the _type_ of object it points to.  It obviously doesn't need to store that at run-time, because it's compile-time information, but it is important to understand, especially on platforms where different pointer types are represented differently.

Comment: @TobySpeight the *compiler* knows because the code specifies the type. I was addressing *"Can the original struct be reconstructed"* and the answer to that is 'no', because the pointer contains no information of that kind. It has to be obtained by dereferencing the pointer. The original `struct` isn't reconstructed, it's either present or it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just do it and it works.

```
uintptr_t v = …;
struct someStruct *s = (void *)v;
struct someStruct valueOfS = *s;
```

As for whether it is legal by the spec, it depends on how you got the value of `v`.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose the memory address of a struct in C language is stored in a variable of sufficiently wide integer type, such as `uintptr_t`.
> I want to read the contents of struct by casting the integer to a struct pointer and dereferencing that.

> Can the original struct be reconstructed using this approach?

It depends on what you mean by "memory address".  If you start with a pointer to a struct, obtained in some way that is well defined by C, and convert that to a suitably wide integer by typecast, then you can recover the original pointer value by casting back.  In this case, you do not need to *reconstruct* the original struct, as you have a pointer to that struct itself.  But you can certainly make a copy if you like.  The most pedantically correct way of doing this might look like so:

```
    struct my_struct s = {0};
    uintptr_t address_as_integer = (uintptr_t) (void *) &s;
    struct my_struct *pointer_to_s = (struct my_struct *) (void *) address_as_integer;
    struct my_struct copy_of_s = *pointer_to_s;
```

In practice, nobody uses those intermediate casts to `void *`.

**ON THE OTHER HAND**, if you have some idea of "memory address" that does not involve a prior C conversion of an appropriate pointer value to integer type, then the behavior of converting your integer to a pointer is implementation defined.  If you choose an integer that happens to correspond to a value that you could have constructed via the approach described previously, then you **probably** can convert and dereference in the way already described, but C does not require that you can.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `uintptr_t` is intended for.  If we have a pointer to to void and cast it to `uintptr_t`, we can portably cast it back to the same pointer to void, which in turn can be safely cast back to recover the original pointer to structure:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct s {
    int n;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct s the_object = { 4 };
    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)(void*)&the_object;

    assert(((struct s*)(void*)p)->n == 4);
}
```

Note that the usual requirement of "liveness" applies - if you `free()` the memory containing the structure, or it was in automatic storage of a function that has returned, then the recovered pointer is just as invalid as any other dangling pointer to the deleted object (i.e. UB if dereferenced).

This is all predicated on your target platforms actually having a `uintptr_t`, of course.  The Standard says this is an *optional* type (though I'm not aware of any compilers that don't provide it).

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common way of accessing hardware registers mapped into the address space.

Example (STM32 uC):

```
#define __IO volatile

typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;     /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset register,      Address offset: 0x18      */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define GPIOA ((GPIO_TypeDef *)0x40000500ULL)

int setModer(uint32_t x)
{
    GPIOA -> MODER = x;
}
```